# Way to determine if a group of touching nodes assigned values in a graph can be added to a specific value?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I have abstracted my actual problem into a more general graph problem for the sake of asking.

I have an undirected graph where each node is assigned an integer. How can I determine whether or not there exists in the graph a group of touching nodes that add to a specific value?

[image: An example graph]

Edit: More specifics: I have a grid of tiles that are labeled with either a positive or negative integer. A single "move" would be to combine any one tile with an adjacent tile (not diagonal), leaving a gap in the grid behind. If the tile being combined into has a value of zero now, it also is removed. I basically need to do a test after every time a tile that has a value of 0 is removed in order to see if any more possible "moves" that result in values of 0 exist in the grid, even if it takes multiple combinations to get to them.

The grid is only 6x6.

I suppose since I only need to test if at least one "zeroing" still exists in the grid, most of the time it wouldn't be hitting the worst case. It can stop searching as soon as it finds one.

Comment: Sure smells NP-complete to me.  You may want to describe your actual problem and let SOers look for shortcuts...

Comment: Can you move a tile with a number into the location of a tile that has been removed? If I understand you correctly, if you first move the 1 into the 8 to form 9, then that 9 into the -9 to remove it, you will have isolated the 4. Can this be moved now, for instance to combine with the 3 to form 7, in order to combine with -7 to remove it? Or would you have to find a way to do moves one at a time for eventually to remove soemthing? In other words, can you move/combine a tile without having to remove something every move?

Comment: How big are the integers? For example, do you know that they'll always be between -100 and 100, or something like that?

Comment: For instance, you might take the 4 and move into -9 to form -5. Then you would take the 3 and move into -7 to form -4, then move the -4 into the -5 to form -9 (again), then move 1 into 8 to form 9, and 9 into -9 to remove it, leaving the bottom row untouched and the rest empty. Would this be legal moves? If so, what exactly is your question?

Comment: Tiles cannot be moved into empty spaces. You'd have to plan around that fact until a point where the empty spaces are refilled. Value ranges vary from -100 to 100

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward approach is to consider each group of touching nodes and solve the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) on them.

Whether this is affordable obviously depends on what sort of graph you have and what the exact definition of touching nodes is. Is it just a particular node and its neighbours? In that case, your diagram makes this look tractable, as no node has more than four neighbours. If n grows with the size of the graph, you are probably in trouble.

Edit - add 6x6 answer

On a 6x6 grid a modification of one of the subset sum algorithms looks expensive but not impossible.

With 18 nodes in the top half of the grid, there are 2^18 patterns of nodes, including the null pattern, which you can ignore, and some of these can't make contiguous patterns even if e.g. they match a bottom half made up of all 18 nodes, so you can generate and store all of the possible ones, e.g. by backtrack search. An 18-bit bitmap and a sum doesn't even take up that much space per pattern. You finish early if any sum to zero. If not, discard all the patterns with no nodes on the lowest line, and keep the rest.

Repeat - swapping lowest for highest - with the bottom half, and then, for each node in the top half, look at all the bottom half patterns with their sum the -ve of the top half sum. If the lowest top half line meets up with the highest bottom half line and the result is contiguous you have a solution. If you didn't get any early zero sums, and none of the a + (-a) patterns match up, then there is no solution.

Comment: I think that a “group of touching nodes” means any subgraph that is connected.